# Rails 5.2 assets not loaded properly on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production

I'm using a wrapbootstarp template for a rails project, I move all css and js files to vendors/assets when running the application in development it load all assets (css & js) properly but in heroku it shows a blank page.

I have tried precompiling the assets manually but still shows a blank page. The weird things is that assets are loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-95017034c76c900be6f5471a85b9cbc01136147254c81d0bb0b25ee5ea4795c7.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/application-aa7d1978d221c464c99b122177a647765fc068f540c747c6ebc14a1771a2b898.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

This is my application.js and application.css:
**js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

//= require js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
//= require js/bootstrap.min.js
//= require js/owl.carousel.min.js
//= require js/wow.min.js
//= require js/waypoints.min.js
//= require js/jquery.counterup.min.js
//= require inc/lightbox/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
//= require inc/lightbox/js/lightbox.js
//= require js/fakeLoader.min.js
//= require js/scrolltopcontrol.js
//= require js/bootstrap-4-navbar.js
//= require js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
//= require slick/slick.min.js
//= require js/color-switcher.js
//= require js/color-switcher-active.js
//= require js/custom.js
```

**css**

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self

 *= require css/bootstrap.min.css
 *= require fonts/css/fontawesome-all.min.css
 *= require css/animate.css
 *= require css/bootstrap-4-navbar.css
 *= require slick/slick.css
 *= require inc/lightbox/css/jquery.fancybox.css
 *= require css/owl.carousel.min.css
 *= require css/owl.theme.default.min.css
 *= require css/fakeLoader.css
 *= require css/magnific-popup.css
 *= require style.css
 *= require color/color-switcher.css
 *= require css/responsive.css
```

**Full server log**

````
2019-07-09T03:06:04.554365+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-07-09T03:06:05.778974+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2019-07-09T03:06:05.789818+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2019-07-09 03:06:05 +0000 ===
2019-07-09T03:06:05.789828+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2019-07-09T03:06:05.789925+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-07-09T03:06:05.762376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-07-09T03:06:05.885244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-07-09T03:06:08.816439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 9411`
2019-07-09T03:06:18.069154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-07-09T03:07:30.326358+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sfaai.herokuapp.com request_id=75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac fwd="73.179.45.178" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=28535 protocol=https
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222866+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222890+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222892+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222895+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222897+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.5-p157), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222899+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222901+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222903+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9411
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222905+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2019-07-09T03:07:30.222921+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.222725 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac] Started GET "/" for 73.179.45.178 at 2019-07-09 03:07:30 +0000
2019-07-09T03:07:30.238573+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.238463 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac] Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2019-07-09T03:07:30.268578+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.268461 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-07-09T03:07:30.281799+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.281698 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_sliders.html.erb (4.7ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.284344+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.284063 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_about.html.erb (0.9ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.288207+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.288138 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_services.html.erb (1.6ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.294139+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.294068 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_doctors.html.erb (3.7ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.298777+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.298711 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_testimonials.html.erb (1.3ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.301639+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.301574 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (29.7ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.307812+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.307741 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_top_menu.html.erb (2.6ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.311383+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.311315 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_main_menu.html.erb (1.0ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.315240+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.315173 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac]   Rendered layouts/partials/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
2019-07-09T03:07:30.317914+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-07-09T03:07:30.317846 #4]  INFO -- : [75acf86b-661c-4eb8-bc14-7a1f06668bac] Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 51.3ms)```
````

Comment: Are you getting any asset loading errors in your web console?

Comment: No, I'm not getting errors.

Comment: Perhaps including a full server-startup log from Heroku would be a good idea. Restart the dyno, and try to load the page you're having a problem with. Then include the full server log in your post. The asset pipeline has nothing to do with your raw HTML, so if you genuinely have a blank page, your issue isn't assets.

Comment: I just restart my dyno and added the server log at the end of my question.

Comment: Nothing about your server logs look abnormal. You said you see a "blank page" what exactly are you seeing? My (I think typical) definition of a blank page is an empty page with no contents. As in, just white, no text.

Comment: Exactly, empty page with no content, but if I inspect the page with chrome the content is there.

Comment: url: https://sfaai.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are styling your `body` tag with `display: none;`. You don't see anything on the page because the contents are hidden.

If you've included `display: none;` in your CSS directly, just remove it. If somehow your choice of css framework or other javascript libraries are causing it, you'll need to figure out why this style would be placed on the body tag.

When I remove the style with the Chrome inspector, I see the site:

[image: the visible site]